# Retrieve IPv6 address of website using terminal

Tags: ipv6, nslookup

Both the nslookup and host commands return IPv4 addresses only. How can i retrieve the IPv6 address of a website using the terminal?

(I have googled around, unfortunately I couldn't find anything useful)

Comment: host does return IPv6 addresses if they're available.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need a way to specify that you want to retrieve an AAAA record instead of an A record. You'll want to use the dig command for this, which is the replacement for nslookup anyways.

```
dig AAAA websitehostname
```

or if you don't want the verbose output:

```
dig AAAA +short websitehostname
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is to ask for the AAAA resource:

```
nslookup -query=AAAA $hostname
```

And:

```
dig AAAA $hostname
```